# How do i show the image as selected on touch of a particular image?

Tags: android

I am using image adapter along with grid view to display certain images with caption.

After user touch an image then press a button this image is loaded on the next screen. 
Right now when a user touch an image it does not show as being selected.

I want to know is there a way to show selected image after a user touch a particular image.

Answer (score 1):

Use selector drawable for the ImageView. Add onClickListner to the ImageView and and in Onclick() method change the ImageView state to sleceted (Image with tick mark on top right or something..)

Comment: thanks for replying. I am using following code : grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     index=position;
     pos=position+1;     
        
    }

   
  });                                                                 Can you please help me how can i change imageview state here?